# aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block fails to create while terraform apply

Tags: terraform-provider-aws

i am going my first steps in Terraform for AWS and i want to create an S3 bucket and set "block all public access" to ON.

Versions:

Terraform v0.12.24
+ provider.aws v2.60.0

file provider.tf

```
provider "aws" {
    region  = "eu-west-1"
    profile = "<myprofile>"
}
```

file s3.tf

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "<myname>" {
    bucket = "<myname>"
    region  = "eu-west-1"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block" "<myname>" {
    bucket = "aws_s3_bucket.<myname>.id"
    block_public_acls = true
    block_public_policy = true
    ignore_public_acls = true
    restrict_public_buckets = true
}
```

the values in <> are my own values and if its the same value on my file, i used the same example value here (so in the s3.tf file its just one name for all the variables)

if i make a

```
terraform apply
```

it will create everything, but at the "aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block" it will go into a timeout after like 1 minute and tell me:

```
Error: error creating public access block policy for S3 bucket (aws_s3_bucket.<myname>.id): NoSuchBucket: The specified bucket does not exist
        status code: 404
```

i also tried to add

```
depends_on = [ aws_s3_bucket.<myname> ]
```

in the "aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block" but it doesnt work either.

I searched and tried and searched but nothing really works.
Someone reported an error about it and told i must set the AWS_REGION globally in an .env file, tried it and didnt work either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your reference to S3 bucket is incorrect.

Change:

```
bucket = "aws_s3_bucket.<myname>.id"
```

To:

```
bucket = aws_s3_bucket.<myname>.id
```

No double quotes since you are referencing another resource

Comment: you are my hero! it really worked! Thank you so much!